# After redirect to a route it immediatly going to the previous page

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

It returns back to the previous page when redirect to a route using an anchor tag with `[routerLink]` or through the `code` using :

```
router.navigate(['/path'])
```

**Example :** If I redirect to the `extractedData` page from result page, it will just show the `extractedData` page then immediately redirecting to the result page.This is my routing module.

```
export const routes:Routes=[
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {path:'home', component:HomeComponent, data:{title:'Home'}},
    {path:'list',component:ListComponent, data:{title:'List'}},
    {path:'resultDetails',component:ResultDetailsComponent,data:{title:'Result Details'}},
    {path:'result',component:ResultComponent,data:{title:'Result'}},
    {path:'extractedData',component:ExtractedDataComponent,data:{title:'Extracted Data'}}
]
```

Comment: your routes file looks fine.. `router.navigate['/path']` is wrong, it should be `router.navigate(['/path'])`.. But we can't help much with only the code you are showing.

Comment: @callback Thanks bro.. I've updated the question. Still I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
router.navigate['/extractedData']
```